# How to set the path of “Application Finder” in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, xfwm4

In Xfce, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> opens a dialog "Application Finder" (`xfce4-appfinder -c`). How to customize the $PATH of Xfce's session that is used for auto-completing and running the command?

(It's not the $PATH of `.profile` or `.bashrc`)

Comment: What version of Xfce? Well, you may consider using a different application launcher instead. One possibility is [xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin](http://gottcode.org/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin/). Another is `gmrun`; I'm pretty confident that `gmrun` uses the same path as Bash.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit late to the party, but for some reason Appfinder was finding things in my customized $PATH for a long time, before suddenly it stopped some time ago.

So, if you're using xinit, then put a file into /etc/X11/Xsession.d/ before the `55xfce4-session` file. Like this:

```
/etc/X11/Xsession.d$ cat 49add-user-path 
[ -d "$HOME/bin" ] && PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

And log out, log in, and $PATH is propagated nicely among running components.

Answer (score 3):

Xfce does not check `.profile`, and `.bashrc` is only used for interactive bash shells. If you want to add path variables, one way is to add them to `~/.pam_environment`. However, the syntax is a little bit different from the usual profile files.

Below is an example to add `~/bin` to the path used by Application finder:

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:${HOME}/bin
```

Comment: Note that this might be Ubuntu-specific, not a feature from XFCE itself: I tried it on Debian Jessie (XFCE 4.10) and it didn't work, Alt+F2 still does not see the programs in `~/bin`.